# How to find case sensitive keys in TreeView nodes using c#?

Tags: c#

I have parents node with duplicate keys but with different case, In a for each loop of a string array I am just checking that case sensitive string exist or not in Parent nodes keys.

```
string[] array1=["hello","HellO"];
foreach(string a in array1){
    if (parentNode.Nodes.ContainsKey(a ))
    {
        console.writeline("string 'HellO' exist in node");
    }
}
```

Comment: What does not work? Is there exception? Is the result different from what you are expecting? If so, what are you expecting and what is the result? It's difficult to tell what your specific problem is.

Comment: i want to search case sensitive text in Nodes

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use below code to do this?

```
String.Equals("string a", "string b", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

That is the most easiest way to compare strings by avoiding case sensitive data.

Hope this helps!